# SpriteKit Pause Resume Error

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, resume

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
let touch = touches.first
let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)
if continueButton.contains(touchLocation) {
    scene?.view?.isPaused = false
    pauseMenu.removeFromParent()
    self.addChild(pauseButton)
    self.addChild(upButton)
    continueButton.removeFromParent()
}
}
```

I am having a Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT error when touches ended on the continue button. Something I have found is that if I declare the sprite (continue button) in touches ended the button does not get removed, however, when I declare the continue button sprite outside the function the continue button is removed.The problem is that sometimes the app will just crash showing the thread 1 error. Any ideas on how I can stop the crashing?

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
var mainturret = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Main Turret")
var pauseButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pause Simbol")
var angleToShoot = 0
var touchIsOn = 0
var pointTwoSecondInterval = 0
let pauseMenu = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Paused")
var zombieSpawningTimer = Timer()
var upButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Up Button")
let downButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Down Button")
let popUpMenu = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "TurretSpot")
var continueButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Continue")
...}
```

This is where the buttons are declared (outside the functions)

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Error occurs on the third line of code.
This is what the computer tells me.

> 2017-06-30 07:32:26.053429-0600 Survive the Night[4635:1030550] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which
>   already has a parent:  name:'(null)'
>   texture:[ 'Up Button' (200 x 200)] position:{0, -254}
>   scale:{0.57, 0.57} size:{56.800003051757812, 56.800003051757812}
>   anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x188da6fd8 0x187808538 0x188da6f20 0x1984f1738 0x1984f1664 0x100073d40 0x100074908 0x1984d7050
>   0x18ef0a46c 0x18ef05804 0x18eed6418 0x18f6cff64 0x18f6ca6c0
>   0x18f6caaec 0x188d55424 0x188d54d94 0x188d529a0 0x188c82d94
>   0x18a6ec074 0x18ef3b130 0x100078c5c 0x187c9159c) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: you need to post more code,  one of your buttons do not exist and is being read as nil

Comment: I have added some context to the code and have shown where the variables have been declared because that is what I believe to be the source of my problems. Hope this is enough :)

Comment: wait, are you using scene kit?

Comment: I'm using gameplay kit and sprite kit.

Comment: Please also add the details of the error, eg what is printed in the console and what line of code the app crashes on. As KnightOfDragon said, it could be that a node is nil while you are trying to access it. Another problem that can occur is that a node already has a parent, and when you call addChild on the node again, the app crashes because a node can't have two parents.

Comment: I just added in some information on the error

Comment: Ughhhh ::facepalm::: `Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: name`

Comment: Does that mean I called it twice without knowing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because that you are adding `upButton` twice as a child to some node.

Most likely, the the line `self.addChild(upButton)` in your `touchesEnded` method is causing the issue. At that point, verify if `upButton.parent` in `nil`. If not, you have a logical error in your code.